# Can we format the decision tree part of plantuml with a different color

Tags: plantuml

I'm trying to put a part of the plantuml where there's an if else condition to be in a different color. I know that a plantUml like the following can be used to color the end states , but I'm trying to color the decision part (if block) in the plantUml. Is that possible?

```
@startuml
if (color it) then (yes)
  #Orange: Colored;
else (no)
   : Not Colored;
endif;
@enduml
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by albert, skinparam ActivityDiamondBackgroundColor can be a solution, but it has a drawback, it updates all if elements in the diagram:

```
@startuml
skinparam ActivityDiamondBackgroundColor green
if (color it) then (yes)
  #Orange: Colored;
else (no)
  #Transparent : Not Colored;
endif;
if (default color) then (yea)
 :Ok;
endif
@enduml
```

[image]

There is another way to update a background color only under the text in the if diamond:

```
@startuml
if (<back:green>color it) then (yes)
  #Orange: Colored;
else (no)
  #Transparent : Not Colored;
endif;
if (default color) then (yea)
 :Ok;
endif
@enduml
```

As for me, this looks sloppy. But this the only way to color the single if-diamond that I am aware of.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Question is not 100% clear, a picture with what you want might be better. 
From what I see a solution:

```
@startuml
if (color it) then (yes)
  #Orange: Colored;
else (no)
  #Transparent : Not Colored;
endif;
@enduml
```

[image]

Edit: after revisiting the question I think it is a bit cleared. Might be that you want to use a `skinparamer` like `skinparam ActivityDiamondBackgroundColor green` so getting:

```
@startuml
skinparam ActivityDiamondBackgroundColor green
if (color it) then (yes)
  #Orange: Colored;
else (no)
  #Transparent : Not Colored;
endif;
@enduml
```

Resulting in:
[image]